# Printing from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

So i want to print the users in an NSMutableArray. But the strings keep coming out as nil.

here is what i have:

```
int users = 0;

- (IBAction)addNewUser:(id)sender {

    NSString *string;
    string = userNameTextField.text;
    [usernameArray insertObject:string atIndex:users];
    users++;
    [self showUsers];
}
-(void)showUsers{
    for (int i = 0; i < users; i++){
        NSString *s = textView.text;
        NSString *add;
        add = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[usernameArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSString *display = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@", s, add];
        textView.text = display;
    }
}
```

i have also tried

```
-(void)showUsers{
    for (int i = 1; i < users; i++){
        NSString *s = textView.text;
        NSString *add;
        add = [usernameArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *display = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@", s, add];
        textView.text = display;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `textView` and `usernameArray` are not `nil`?

Comment: how can i check to see if usernameArray is nil?

Comment: Use the debugger and add an `NSLog` statement.

Comment: NSLog(@"%p", usernameArray);

Comment: Allocate usernameArray.
usernameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: i have the alloc statement in the viewDidLoad method. Would that work?

Comment: First `allocate` your `NSMutableArray` then use `addObject:` method instead of `insertObject:` method, this is extra work.

Comment: [usernameArry addObject:string];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try using more comprehensive names for the objects. I'm rewriting your code. 
**Common Causes for the problem : Array not initialized**, you are starting your **for cycle with int i equal to 1, so you are missing the object at index 0** at your mutable array. Try the following code.

```
@interface InterfaceName : InterfaceInherits <IfDelegate> {
int usersCount;
NSMutableArray * usernameArray;

}

@implementation InterfaceName 
/*There's no more confident way to initialize a variable than in the init method of the class. */
-(id)init{
usersCount = 0;
//You have to be sure that your array is not nil
usernameArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init]];
return self; 
}
- (IBAction)addNewUser:(id)sender {
NSString *username = [usernameTextField text];
[usernameArray insertObject:username atIndex:usersCount];
usersCount++;

//I'll omit the display as I'm not sure what you were doing with it. 
}
-(void)showUsers{
for (int i = 0; i < usersCount; i++){
    NSString *retrievedUser = [usernameArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *display = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User Retrieved : %@",retrievedUser];
    textView.text = display;
}
}


    @end
```